# How Do I Open A PDF In Sitecore

Tags: pdf, sitecore, sitecore6

How do I open a pdf document stored in Sitecore when a user clicks a link?  The pdf document is stored in the Media Library.
Here's the code I have now:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = item.Fields["Url"];
tab.NavigateUrl = linkField.Url;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same rules apply to a PDF media as to any other type in media library. If you need just to retrieve the media url to construct a link, do the following:

```cs
MediaItem mediaItem = linkField.TargetItem;
if(mediaItem != null)
MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
```

You can also simply use  web control or xsl control to render the link:
Web control:

```xml
<sc:Link Field="Url" Item="if you need to process specific item" runat="server" />
```

If your question concerns browser behavior when the link is clicked, set ForceDownload to true:

```xml
<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
  <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
  **<forceDownload>true</forceDownload>**
  <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/pdf</sharedTemplate>
  <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/pdf</versionedTemplate>
</mediaType>
```

Comment: The MediaUrlOptions that can be passed to the MediaManager don't seem to correspond to the UrlOptions that a link manager uses. Is it possible to specify something like UrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl for the MediaManager?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of problems with Firefox on a Mac, as PDFs wont seem to work there.

For that you need to setup some stuff according to [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/media%20files%20downloaded%20with%20ashx%20extension.aspx).

if you can't access that is basically tells you to go to the web.config, find this:

```xml
<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
```

and change the

```xml
<forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
```

to

```xml
<forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
```